# How to integrate my own tflite model on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have completed a tensorflow model than converted it correctly to tflite in order to use it in a mobile app using flutter. I didn't know how to integrate a personalized tflite model with flutter. All the available examples use the pretrained models. When I tried my model, the camera launches for a while and stops immediately!
[image]

I followed the source code from this link which uses the "tflite" pacakge : https://medium.com/@shaqian629/real-time-object-detection-in-flutter-b31c7ff9ef96
I added my own tflite model alongside with other models in all the ".dart" files and in "pubspec.yaml".

Comment: In my opinion you just need to follow the article, replace the model with our own and verify if all the model inputs and outputs are correct. I think that this description lacks more information to be able to help more precisely :)

Answer (score 2):

you can try the '[tflite_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter)' package. 'tflite' package is not suitable for custom trained models as you will get shape incompatible error message